# Is a Transaction active when a IBQuery component is active

Tags: database, delphi, firebird, interbase

When opening a TIBQuery (IBQuery.Open), is the correspondig Transaction active only the time the data is fetched from the DB or as long as IBQuery is closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transaction is active while IBQuery is open.

Comment: which is the same as "Active = True".